# How to redirect to JSF page from JAX-RS method?

Tags: jsf, redirect, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS resource and after resolve business logic I want to show the results in a JSF page. How can I do that?

```
@Path("/rest")
public class PaymentServiceRest {

    @GET
    @Path("/status")
    public String method()  {

        // Business logic...

        return "results.xhtml"; // how to return a jsf page? 
    }
}
```

The first time the client access the app is using the url, i.e: `http://myApp/rest/status`, then do some logic and based on that do a redirection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I've found a way to **forward** from a JAX-RS method to a JSF page:

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces("text/html")
public Response test(@Context ServletContext context,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @Context HttpServletResponse response) {

    try {
        String myJsfPage = "/response.xhtml";
        context.getRequestDispatcher(myJsfPage).forward(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException | IOException ex) {
        return Response.status(NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
    return null;
}
```

As described here: https://www.java.net//forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/forwarding-jsf-jax-rs

The injection via the method can also be done via injection in fields, that is a matter of 'preference'

This have been tested in TomEE (Apache CXF). I'm just a little curious if this is just a dirty "hack" or if there is a better way to do it.

---

**UPDATE**

I found a better way to **redirect** that renders the JSF tags without any issues (in my case tags such as `<p:graphicImage/>` were not rendering properly)

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces("text/html")
public Response test(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
    String myJsfPage = "/response.xhtml";
    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
    response.sendRedirect(contextPath + myJsfPage);
    return Response.status(Status.ACCEPTED).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between those two solutions:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

@Path("/rest")
public class PaymentServiceRest {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @Context 
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    /**
     * This method uses the injected request/response in the PaymentServiceRest class
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @GET
    @Path("/status1")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response method1() throws IOException {
        String myJsfPage = "/views/index.xhtml";
        String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
        response.sendRedirect(contextPath + myJsfPage);
        return Response.status(Status.ACCEPTED).build();
    }

    /**
     * This method uses the injected request/response passed as parameters
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @GET
    @Path("/status2")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response method2(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        String myJsfPage = "/views/index.xhtml";
        String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
        response.sendRedirect(contextPath + myJsfPage);
        return Response.status(Status.ACCEPTED).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: And how is this different from the update in the accepted and highly upvoted answer? Just the 'injection' part? That is 'trivial' and not really related to the problem

Answer (score -1):

java class file

```
public String processPage1(){
      return "page";
   }
```

in faces-config.xml

```
<navigation-case>
      <from-action>#{navigationController.processPage1}</from-action>
      <from-outcome>page</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>page1.jsf</to-view-id>
   </navigation-case>
```

visit this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_page_navigation.htm)

Comment: do this for redirection: `"page1?faces-redirect=true"`

Comment: go through this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-page-forward-vs-page-redirect/)

Comment: this is just a jsf redirect, inside jax-rs methods only will print the returned String, thanks for your time.